# Adding "Like" Button/Box code to site using Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, dreamweaver, cs4

I am new at designing websites.  I would like to insert FB's "Like" Box into my website.  I am using Dreamweaver CS4.
I am on the FB's Like Button/Box generator page.
I received the code.
I tried putting it into my index.dwt page where I want it to be, and it does not show up.
Any suggestions?  Thanks so much!
Update: I am still getting nowhere with this!! I've been trying everything I read in help topics, and nothing is working! My head is about to explode... PLEASE if anyone knows how to help, let me know.  Thanks in advance.

***I posted the codes I'm using in comments below... thanks

Comment: Does it not show up in the preview? Or does it not show up even when you preview it in a browser?

Comment: how are you previewing the page? and paste the code your pasting in the index page to your question.

Comment: it does not show in the preview on DW, or the website itself after i Site|Put

Comment: The code I'm using is this: the html5: <script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=112520765520252&xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Sky-Top-Vending-Inc/156991511053872" data-send="true" data-width="480" data-show-faces="true"></div>

Comment: ...and also tried the xfbml: <script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=112520765520252&xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Sky-Top-Vending-Inc/156991511053872" send="true" width="480" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

Comment: I was at least able to get a "page badge" onto my website, so I think I'll be happy with that for now... Thanks everyone

Comment: I have the same exact problem. The button only seems to appear once I actually load the page onto my server

Answer (score 0):

Heather I tried your generated code and generated code for my site too and both do not work.

Use this simple code: (replace the putyoursitehere and yourhomepage with your own)

You can change the properties to fit your own.

If the code doesn't come through, go to this page, view source and copy FB code.
http://diananashif.com/fb_code.html

Hope this helps,

Diana